# How to share a UI element between two classes with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a basic `WkWebView`, yet would like two different classes to be able to access it.

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
     var webView = WKWebView()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
         self.view.addSubview(webView)
     }
}
```

**SwiftJavascriptBridge.swift**

```
class SwiftJavascriptBridge: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
     //How can I access webView here?
}
```

As you can see, I create my `webView` variable within my `ViewController`, but would also like to access it from my `SwiftJavascriptBridge.swift`. How am I able to achieve this so that both classes can make edits to my web view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class WKWebViewFactory {
    let webView = WKWebView()

    static var sharedInstance = WKWebViewFactory()
}
```

Then access the web view as `WKWebViewFactory.sharedInstance.webView`

Comment: Just getting an error of `Use of unresolved identifier 'WKWebView'` at `let webView = WKWebView()`

Comment: Add `import WebKit` to your file.

Comment: Yep, just worked that out. Derp moment, my bad. Testing it out now.

Comment: All seems to work well. Although, how would I use it for functions such as this one, which tracks when the webview is loaded - `func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) { print("loaded") }`

Comment: In this case you can use the webView that is passed to this function itself.

Comment: So no need to change anything there?

Comment: I was referring to how the `WKWebViewFactory.sharedInstance.webView` is attached to that function so that I can track when it is finished loading. Because replacing `func webView` with `func WKWebViewFactory.sharedInstance.webView` throws an error.

Comment: You can use that as well if that the only web view you are using. Anyways it will be the same instance that is passed to the delegate method.

Comment: Sorry, little confused. The function was `func webView`, but changing it to `func WKWebViewFactory.sharedInstance.webView` throws an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104284/discussion-between-pradeep-k-and-fizzix).